# How to confine OnEdit(e) to a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to sort a range of a sheet based on column J(10) but I only want it to sort when cells between N9 and AG190 are edited.

Currently, any edit anywhere triggers a sort, and that's no bueno.

I've cobbled together the following, but really I have no idea what I'm doing

```
function myFunction() {

}

function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 10;
  var startColumn = 14;
  var endColumn = 33;
  var tableRange = "a9:cq188";

  if((editedCell.getColumn() <= endColumn || editedCell.getColumn() >= startColumn)) {   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
   range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
  }
}
```

First time posting here, thanks for any assist

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  //if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='DesiredSheet Name')return;//you might want to put something like this in here to limit its operation to a single sheet
  if(e.range.columnStart>=14 && e.range.columnStart<=33 && e.range.rowStart>=9 & e.range.rowStart<=190) {   //N9 and AG190
    e.range.getSheet().getRange("A9:CQ188").sort({column:10,ascending:false});
  }
}
```